# place-images not defined DrRacket

Tags: racket

In the teachpack 2htdp image, there is a function place-images, which takes a list of images and a list of posn, and places them on a scene.

http://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpimage.html

Trying to run this function in DrRacket

```
(require 2htdp/image)

(place-images
   (list (circle 4 "solid" "white")
     (circle 4 "solid" "white")
     (circle 4 "solid" "white")
     (circle 4 "solid" "white"))
   (list (make-posn 18 20)
     (make-posn 0 6)
     (make-posn 14 2)
     (make-posn 8 14))
(rectangle 24 24 "solid" "goldenrod"))
```

Results in "place-images is not defined". Which is strange because place-image works completely fine for me, anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: What version of Racket are you using? This function is probably only available in Racket v5.92 and on.

Comment: I can confirm that the function is in 5.92 and later, not in 5.3.6 and earlier.

Comment: Try to use Advanced Student and remove the first line "#lang racket".